# Хранение учетных данных в приложении Android

Tags: android, шифрование, пароль, хранение-данных, декомпиляция

Столкнулись с данной проблемой при разработке двух приложений. Первое приложение использует отправку e-mail сообщений и должно хранить учетные данные для входа на  smtp-сервер. Есть опасность декомпиляции apk и получения данных доступа третьими лицами. Во втором приложении все еще серьёзнее: программа вознаграждает пользователя биткоинами и должна хранить в себе данные доступа к биткоин-кошельку.
Использование обфускатора Proguard не решает проблему, а только слегка усложняет процесс анализа кода.
Как решить данную проблему? Возможности использования сервера нет.

Comment: [Android keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) system?

Comment: @pavlofff, интересный вариант, спасибо. Мы никогда не использовали keystore для таких целей, не подскажете, как сохранить в него необходимые ключи?